# Full-width images distort on orientation change

Tags: html, ios, css, image

My site is essentially a row of alternating full-width divs and images.

I'm experiencing weird behavior on mobile devices (iPhone and iPad, specifically). The page loads fine. When I rotate the phone, the image distorts to a super-massive size. When I rotate it back, it distorts to an even greater size. Essentially, the image becomes unusable.

**Questions:** Why does this happen? Is there a better way to implement the CSS so this can be avoided? If not, what's the simplest javascript fix to the problem?

Here's the CSS for the image div:

```
div.pic-container-1
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    background: url(../images/rt2.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Here are screenshots (iPhone):

Initial load:

[image]

Rotate to landscape:

[image]

Back to portrait:

[image]

Comment: I experienced similar because of the **vw/vh** unit settings. Try to change them for testing.

Comment: That did it. Changed the height to `%` instead of `vh`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`height:80vh`

to

`height:80%`